# python : problem with insertion in a list

Tags: python

I have written the following code that works and the output is what it is expected :

```
myList1=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
myList2=["abc","def","ghi"]
myList3=[]
for i in range(3):
    temp=myList1[i]
    temp.insert(0,myList2[i])
    myList3.append(temp)
print(myList3)
```

But when I try to write the same code without the `temp` variable, it does not work.

```
myList1=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
myList2=["abc","def","ghi"]
myList3=[]
for i in range(3):
    myList3.append(myList1[i].insert(0,myList2[i]))
print(myList3)
```

And this code, also, does not work.

```
myList1=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
myList2=["abc","def","ghi"]
myList3=[]
for i in range(3):
    temp=myList1[i].insert(0,myList2[i])
    myList3.append(temp)
print(myList3)
```

I think there are some python fundamentals that I have not understood.

Any comments and help will be appreciated.

Thanks for answer

Comment: ```.insert``` returns ```None``` so you get ```None,None,None```

Comment: Yes. I know that but why it returns  `None`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.insert` is an inplace function. It returns `None` or nothing. If you don't want to use `temp`, you can use `zip()`

```
myList1=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
myList2=["abc","def","ghi"]
myList3=[]
for i,j in zip(myList1,myList2):
    i.insert(0,j)
    myList3.append(i)
print(myList3)
```

A compact solution:

```
myList1=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
myList2=["abc","def","ghi"]

myList3=[[j]+i for i,j in zip(myList1,myList2)]
print(myList3)
```

Comment: Thanks for the keyword : `inplace function`

Comment: The sighingnow comment makes me in trouble (see its answer and comments). As I am a python beginner. I am going to read some docs about `inplace function`. I let you discuss with Sighingnow.

Answer (score 1):

`.insert` of `list` returns `None`, rather than the result list.

To avoid the usage of temporary variable `tmp`, you could have

```py
myList1=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
myList2=["abc","def","ghi"]
myList3=[]
for i in range(3):
    myList3.append(myList2[i:i+1] + myList1[i])
print(myList3)
```

Or

```py
myList1=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
myList2=["abc","def","ghi"]
myList3=[]
for i in range(3):
    myList3.append([myList2[i]] + myList1[i])
print(myList3)
```

Comment: I see that. But why `None` is returned

Comment: This is how `list.insert` is implemented. And has noting to do with "inplace function". You could define a inplace insert function as

```python
def insert(xs, idx, x):
     xs.insert(idx, x)
     return xs
```

It is a inplace function, but it doesn't return `None`.

Comment: Your comment makes me in trouble. As I am a python beginner. I am going to read some docs about `inplace function`. I let you discuss with Sujay.

Comment: Inplace function means the function operates on its argument, but inplace function do could have meaningful returns.

Comment: Do you have  link / blog / discussion to advise me ?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at your last example:
The line: temp=myList1[i].insert(0,myList2[i]) does change your list "myList1"! The problem is, that the result of the insert will return "None".

So something like this would work, but not be pretty:

```
myList1=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
myList2=["abc","def","ghi"]
myList3=[]
for i in range(3):
    myList1[i].insert(0,myList2[i])
    myList3.append(myList1[i])
print(myList3)
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Sujay give me the answer. `insert` is a inplace function